EasyRandom Unable to create type XMLGregorianCalendar
My project works with SpringBoot and Java 11.
I'm trying to do some unit tests, and to create the objects I'm using easyRandom.
The problem is that in one of this objects I have an XMLGregorianCalendar attribute that is giving me an error when easyRandom tries to initialize the object.
The code in my test is like:
public class CardTest {

static EasyRandom easyRandom=new EasyRandom();

@Test
void  cardTest(){
Card card= easyRandom.nextObject(Card.class);
//other code
}
}

@NoArgsConstructor
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Card", propOrder = {
"name",
"date",
"adress"
})
public class Card{

protected String name;

@XmlSchemaType(name = "date")
protected XMLGregorianCalendar date;

protected String adress;
}

Caused by: org.jeasy.random.ObjectCreationException: Unable to create type: javax.xml.datatype.XMLGregorianCalendar for field: date of class: com.Card
    at org.jeasy.random.FieldPopulator.populateField(FieldPopulator.java:90)
    at org.jeasy.random.EasyRandom.populateField(EasyRandom.java:206)
    at org.jeasy.random.EasyRandom.populateFields(EasyRandom.java:195)
    at org.jeasy.random.EasyRandom.doPopulateBean(EasyRandom.java:162)


I would like to know if someone has ever had this problem and how did you solve it.
Thank you!

I have found a possible solution:
//We indicate to the random to not fullfill the parameter 
EasyRandomParameters parameters = new EasyRandomParameters();
parameters.excludeField(FieldPredicates.named("date").and(FieldPredicates.inClass(Card.class)));
EasyRandom easyRandom=new EasyRandom(parameters);

//We create a XMLGregorianCalendar variable
XMLGregorianCalendar dateGreg = DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(Instant.now().toString());


//We create the object and insert the variable inside
Card card= easyRandom.nextObject(Card.class);
card.setDate(dateGreg);
        


Thanks for answering your own question. Don’t use Date. Your newly created GregorianCalendar is already set to the current date and time in your default time zone, so you can simply leave out the Date and the call to c.setTime(), they make no difference. A more modern option would use java.time. For example, LocalDate today = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault()); and then DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(today.toString()).

I think the most accurate you're going to get is DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(Instant.now().toString()). At a quick glance it looks like 'timezone' in this dialect of XML-speak actually means 'offset'. So it you want to localize it, you'd have to use OffsetDateTime. I could be wrong

@g00se You’re fully correct. I was only wondering whether the annotation @XmlSchemaType(name = "date") means that the XMLGregorianCalendar should only represent the date and not the time of day nor UTC offset. I think the docs hint in that direction without being clear.

@g00se  thanks for your comment, I have added your modifications to the answer.
